# Binary code conversion

Tags: binary

Hello Stackoverflow community.

Today I bring you a question that I still can't understand deeply.

If I give to end users the binary code of my program, is it possible that they can decipher it and actually see how I made my program?

It's possible to transform binary into assembly, but would the assembly be human-readable at the point that someone can reproduce the equivalent in a high-level language and actually "steal" it?

Thank you all and merry Christmas.

Comment: Any code can be decompiled because ultimately it has to be able to run on a processor, so at least the processor will be able to read it. As such, a human can, with the right tools, read it. However, the process of compiling code from source code into binary form is a lossy process. You can't get back the original source, and depending on the programming language and binary code in question, may or may not give you back something really useful.

Comment: So if we talk about a game or a big program the assembly that will be retrieved from the binaries will not be helpfull to find out the way that I have coded my program. Is that wright?